# Skype on Ubuntu: how to disable “Send message” on Enter and enable “New line”

Tags: skype

The question is not about Ubuntu per se, but is related. Hope it will not be banned by severe moderators. Take into account that there is a tag `Skype` here and it has been used 1122 times!

How to disable "Send message" on Enter and enable "New line".
Is there an option on Ubuntu version of Skype? I can't find it.

Comment: Maybe not what you are looking for, but if you type <shift> + <enter> it will do just that.

Comment: @Jean-Marie, yep, I know that. I want to swap those. `Shift+Enter` should be send message.