# disable "enter" as "send message" in Whatsapp

Tags: shortcut-keys, whatsapp

Would you know how to disable "enter" as "send message" in Whatsapp, in a laptop with Ubuntu 22.04?

This question is similar to a previous unanswered one: [Skype on Ubuntu: how to disable “Send message” on Enter and enable “New line”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998291/skype-on-ubuntu-how-to-disable-send-message-on-enter-and-enable-new-line)

Comment: Which Whatsapp client exactly? There are a few for Linux/Ubuntu but not any official client. And then there's the web client which is totally OS aganostic.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using web.whatsapp.

Comment: If so your question is off-topic, it has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new line using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I do not think that can be turned off on WhatsApp web unless you remap your keyboard ([read more about linux keyboard remaping here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/12/remap-keyboard-and-mouse-buttons-on.html)).

Comment: Thanks.I need to disable enter=send message because I accidentally press enter very often.  I would be happy to remap the key, but how to restrict the remapping only to web-whastapp?

Comment: @pable It can't be done. Web is web, OS agnostic, this has nothing to do with Ubuntu, not an Ubuntu question. There are a few unofficial clients you can use instead where ENTER creates a new line instead. Remapping the keyboard CAN'T be done only for a specific web page and doing it for this purpose alone is even more absurd than the question itself.

Comment: Understood, thanks! May I ask then which WA client for Ubuntu would do the job?

Comment: The most suitable solution would be by using an extension. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any so I'm making one